# how to convert EXPECT file to executable file

Tags: linux, scripting, javascript, executable

I am trying to convert EXPECT script that is located in an ubuntu client to a .exe script so that I can execute the EXPECT file from web browser using javascript.

Can anyone guide me on how to convert the .exp file to a .exe?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveState have a [**Tcl Dev Kit**](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit) that should help you do this.